# PHP - Return Class in JSON

Tags: php, json, class

I have a class:

```
class A {
   protected $nome;       

   public function getNome() {
       return $this->nome . " exemplo";
   }

   public function setNome($nome) {
       $this->nome = $nome;
   }
}
```

When i use the code:

```
$r = new A();
$r->setNome("My");
json_encode($r);
```

the code not returns because of the **protected** property, if the property is **public** the code returns but does'nt returns correctly.

Comment: You can look into having your class extend JsonSerializable - http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php.

Comment: Setting as public works for me.

Answer (score -1):

As per the definition of class, we can access only public members outside class. So make $nome for public

```
class A {
    public $nome;  
    public function getNome() {
        return $this->nome . " exemplo";
    }

    public function setNome($nome) {
         $this->nome = $nome;
    }
}
$r = new A(); print_r($r);
$r->setNome("My");
echo json_encode($r);
```

OR

Return results to json_encode(if you don't make $Nome public), see the example:

```
$r = new A();
$r->setNome("My");
echo json_encode($r->getNome());
```